# How to get instances class name

Tags: php, yii2

[image: Class structure]

In a class function i need to know if the current class is called by another class.
Debugging with netbeans/xdebug i can see this class instance has a property called *yii\base\Model*__instances (the current class extends yii\base\Model).

*yii\base\Model*__instances is an array and inside there's an instance of the different classes.
How can i get the key or classname of the first element of this array? (in this case app\models\User) 
Can i access __instances at all?

Comment: What is the real problem you face? Why do you want to determine which class calls your method?

Comment: If the method is called from a certain class (app\models\User) i need to call another function. I already solved this with a workaround, but a cleaner solution would be better.

Comment: If you want a clean solution, drop the idea completely - this is really ugly context-based magic. If method should behave differently depending on context, pass context as method argument.

Answer (score -1):

As above. What is the actual problem you face? To get class in php you can find built-in get_class http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php .
To access the first element of sequential (indexed) array it would be $array[0] , in php 7.3 an above you could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php , on associative array in previous versions of php you could simply iterate over and get the first one.

Comment: But how can i assign \*yii\base\Model\*__instances to a variable (or call array_key_first on it)?

Comment: `get_class` won't list the calling class for a method